# можно ли переиспользовать сокет

Tags: linux, c, сокет

здравствуйте, вот, допустим, есть у меня клиентский сокет... сделали connect, приняли данные/отправили... а можно ли приконнектится к другому адресу, и так же, как ни в чем ни бывало, начать обмен с другим совершенно хостом? я так понимаю, параметр SO_REUSEADDR на это не влияет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Именно, опция SO_REUSEADDR используется только для бинда портов и к исходящим подключениям отношения не имеет.

Comment: а сокет то переиспользовать можно?) прям много раз делать connect() к совершенно разным конечным точкам

Comment: Можно, но только для датаграмм. Когда мы делаем close(), то дескриптор освобождается и сокета более не существует.

Comment: хм, а close то обязательно делать перед connect следующим?

Comment: А вы можете вставить вилку в другую розетку, пока она подключена куда-то еще? Не, можно попробовать конечно. Ровно так, как можно написать код и попробовать его запустить.

Comment: ну я просто по аналогии с sendto методом, там же не нужно подключаться никуда, а прям с одного сокета собачишь на разные адреса

Comment: Это и есть Датаграммы. Их - можно. Это как с катапульты кидать камешки - новую катапульту строить каждый раз не нужно, но и долетит ли камешек - мы не знаем.

Comment: чет я никак не могу найти что sendto нельзя использовать с tcp сокетами

Answer (score 3):

Опция SO_REUSEADDR используется в одном, крайне редком случае - когда **одновременно** две (или более программы) используют **один** сокет. Подробно это описано в гл. 9. "Повышение производительности" книги "Создание сетевых приложений в среде Linux" (Шон Уолтон).